# Can’t get Shippable to run my protractor tests

Tags: angularjs, selenium, continuous-integration, protractor

The errors I get from shippable looks like this

```
Failures:

  1) homepage should have the name of the app in the navbar
   Message:
     Error: Error while running testForAngular: Timed out waiting for async script result after 11002ms
Command duration or timeout: 11.13 seconds
Build info: version: '2.40.0', revision: 'fbe29a9', time: '2014-02-19 20:54:28'
System info: host: '61185b2d1026', ip: '172.17.18.4', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-32-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_67'
Session ID: 71602336-8ec6-44bd-a755-9fc82da1d337
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=29.0}]
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Error while running testForAngular: Timed out waiting for async script result after 11002ms
Command duration or timeout: 11.13 seconds
Build info: version: '2.40.0', revision: 'fbe29a9', time: '2014-02-19 20:54:28'
System info: host: '61185b2d1026', ip: '172.17.18.4', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-32-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_67'
Session ID: 71602336-8ec6-44bd-a755-9fc82da1d337
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=29.0}]
    at Error ()
==== async task ====
WebDriver.executeScript()
    at [object Object]. (/home/shippable/workspace/src/github.com/tipfortip/www/public/index-spec.js:4:13)
==== async task ====
Asynchronous test function: it()
Error
    at [object Object]. (/home/shippable/workspace/src/github.com/tipfortip/www/public/index-spec.js:3:3)
    at Object. (/home/shippable/workspace/src/github.com/tipfortip/www/public/index-spec.js:1:63)

2) homepage should have the name of the app in the footer
   Message:
     Error: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost:8000/ : angular never provided resumeBootstrap
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost:8000/ : angular never provided resumeBootstrap
==== async task ====
WebDriver.executeScript()
    at [object Object]. (/home/shippable/workspace/src/github.com/tipfortip/www/public/index-spec.js:14:13)
==== async task ====
Asynchronous test function: it()
Error
    at [object Object]. (/home/shippable/workspace/src/github.com/tipfortip/www/public/index-spec.js:13:3)
    at Object. (/home/shippable/workspace/src/github.com/tipfortip/www/public/index-spec.js:1:63)
```

I can run the tests successfully with Firefox and Chrome on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the Shippable system did not recognize the bootstrapping that my document was doing. Needed to add it in the HTML of the page that was resolving.

```
angular.element(document).ready -> angular.bootstrap document, ['foo']
```

did not work, needed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="foo">
```